# php code to create new html tables when orderby changes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple script using a sql query to get data from a data base and order information by a certain column.
I want to be able to crate a new html table every time the "Tier" changes as you can see in the query below. How can I break this down so that the tier shows up in a new additional HTML table?
The below gets and displays the info, but there is no way to differentiate the tiers. Any ideas on how to format this?

```
<?php
    // You can place PHP like this

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condenced table-responsive'>";
echo "<tr><th>Channel</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "Channel_Lineup";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT channel, description FROM Channel_LineUps WHERE Market_ID = 1 ORDER BY Tier ASC"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";    

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL statement is not returning the tier, so it will be very difficult to switch on that.

If you change your request to return the tier (putting tier first makes things a touch simpler):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tier, channel, description FROM Channel_LineUps WHERE Market_ID = 1 ORDER BY Tier ASC");
```

Then you can add a `lastTier` value to the `TableRows` class, and have the `beginChildren` function output a table tag if the current tier is different from the last one seen.  You can also can change the `current()` function to not output the 'tier'.

```
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    private $lastTier = NULL;

    function __construct($it) {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        if (parent::key() != "tier") return "<td>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        if ($this->lastTier != parent::current()) {
            if (!is_null($this->lastTier)) echo "</table>\n";
            echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condenced table-responsive'>\n";
            $this->lastTier = parent::current();
        }
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of adding the lastTier value. Works nicely. Thank you Joe

Comment: If I wanted to add a table header or table caption that reflects the Tier, I suspect I could just add in the caption to the function current() ?

Comment: Add it right after the table tag in beginChildren()

Comment: Thanks - I tried using  $this->lastTier right after table. It shows the Tier, however is for the prior tiername in prior table. Any way to show the current tier?

Comment: If you move the `$this->lastTier = parent::current();` line immediately after the `if` in the `beginChildren` function, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Grammar Nazi Disclaimer: I am old and had been doing database since the early 80's.  So I will use the syntax I am familiar with rather than OPs class syntax.

This is my interpretation of what I believe you are trying to do.  I don't always get the interpretation right.  My code is usually very efficient because I have been writing code since the Apple II was released and efficiency was a necessity.

```
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){$lineups[] = $row;}
mysql_free_result($results);
unset($row);
echo '<table>';
foreach ($lineups as $val
  if ($val[0] != $saveTier){
    $saveTier =  $val[0];
    echo '</table><table>';
  }
  echo "<tr><td>$val[0]</td><td>$val[1]</td><td>$val[2]</td><td>$val[3]</td><tr>\n";

}
echo '</table>';
```

I do not use associative keys, only numeric.  In this case your `Tier` is `$row[0]` so edit accordingly. 
If tier is non-numeric change `$saveTier  = -1;` to `$saveTier  = 'x';`

**Notes**

I like to get the entire table into an array first.  This speeds up the table access as it is done all at one time.
I only use numeric keys because they are more efficient.

Comment: Thank you. This works as well, but I chose to implement differently. Thank you so much though. I like the old school approach :) Good stuff